# openldaps wildcard certificate not accepted

Tags: ssl, ldap, openldap

my wildcard certificate doesn't get accepted with ldap 2.4.23. when i try to connect i get the following error:

```
TLS certificate verification: subject:
OID.2.5.29.17=DNS:*.domain.com,CN=*.domain.com,OU=LALALA,O=LALALA S.A.,L=LALALA,ST=LALALA,C=XX,
issuer: E=support@domain.com,CN=LALALA Root C.A.,O=LALALA,L=LALALA,ST=LALALA,C=XX,
cipher: AES-256, security level: high, secret key bits: 256, total key bits: 256,
cache hits: 0, cache misses: 0, cache not reusable: 0
TLS: hostname (openldap1.domain.com) does not match common name in certificate (*.domain.com).
```

**my certificate is: `CN=*.domain.com` AND `subjectAltName=DNS:*.domain.com`**

How can I make it so that my certificate is accepted in LDAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first i've found a page saying that, **wildcards in CN don't work with openldap and you have to use subjectAltName**! (I can't find that page anymore...)

unfortunately, i've created the certificate like this, which is not the subjectAltName, that you need:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
subjectAltName                =Alternativer Name 1
subjectAltName_default        =DNS:*.domain.com
```

that's why it is displaying OID.2.5.29.17 instead of subjectAltName...

i've found the answer for subjectAltName on: http://wiki.cacert.org/VhostTaskForce

> After studing of "RFC 2459 - Section 4.2.1.7: Subject Alternative Name" and crossreferencing to the result of isakmpd's certpatch(8) the following should work: 
>    [...]
>   To accomplish such an CSR the following entries are needed in the openssl.cnf (please note: I only added the relevant parts for this Attribute)
>
> ```
> [ req ]
> req_extensions          = v3_req
> [ v3_req ]
> subjectAltName          = DNS:www.example.com
> ```